# What are the different upgradeability features in the BIP-Taproot (BIP 341) proposal?

Tags: segregated-witness, taproot, bip

What are the different upgradability features in the BIP-Taproot (BIP 341) [proposal](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki)?

Why are there so many upgradability paths? Is there something an annex can do that a leaf version can't?

This question was asked by James Prestwich on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/_prestwich/status/1281747103564222466?s=20).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> There is the annex, leaf version, ext_flag, OP_SUCCESS, unknown pubkey
> types and you could probably include the existing witness version too.
> I believe that list is [exhaustive](https://github.com/sipa/bitcoin/blob/taproot/src/script/interpreter.h#L128L140).
>
> The ext_flag isn't so much an extension mechanism in itself; more a
> structure that permits safely reusing the sighashing code (as opposed
> to needing a new tag or other mechanism for collision avoidance).
>
> - Leaf versions: for revamping script semantics
> - OP_SUCCESSx: for new opcodes, without coordinating new version
> - Pubkey types: for new sighash flags/cryptography without needing an explosion of new opcodes
> - Annex: for effectively adding new fields like nLockTime
>
> Leaf versions were really only added because we had a few bits to
> spare in the control block, and it seemed wasteful to reserve them.
> They're mostly a convenience, I think, as OP_SUCCESSx can achieve the
> same (add an OP_V2 etc).
>
> As the annex isn't committed to by the scriptPubKey, it's more a way
> to extend witness possibilities than it is directly a way to add new
> semantics.
>
> So is there something an annex can do that a new leaf version can't? I
> think they're orthogonal.
>
> For example, a feature where you could restrict a tx to only be valid
> in a chain that contains a certain block hash. It can't be done with a
> leaf version, as it's a sign-time thing. I believe the annex can't be
> used to introduce new script conditions. A new leaf version could
> introduce its own annex-like thing, but that wouldn't be able to apply
> to old leaf versions.
>
> The motivating example for the annex is this. Imagine a new opcode is
> added that needs few bytes but has high CPU cost. You'd want a high
> weight budget per such opcode, but that may require actually stuffing
> the witness with dummy data just to get the necessary budget. Instead,
> it would be nice if there could just be a marker on the input that
> says "increment the apparent weight (and corresponding op budget) by
> N", without taking N bytes. Logistically, it would be annoying if that
> marker can only be parsed when the spent output is available. The
> annex is recognizable without context, mostly by exploiting a thankful
> coincidence about what set of witnesses is valid for v0 (first byte of
> last witness stack item can only take on certain byte values). This, I
> think, can't be accomplished with a new leaf version.

This question was answered by Pieter Wuille on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/pwuille/status/1281755347787542528?s=20).